# Google OAUTH for google fit, once I get some sensitive scopes approved if I add another sensitive scope will I have to reverify?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-fit

I am preparing an app to go through the Google OAUTH verification process to enable some sensitive scopes for google fit.  My question is once I get some sensitive scopes approved if I add another similar sensitive scope later (for example lets say I get /auth/fitness.activity.read approved and then later want to add /auth/fitness.heart_rate.read) will I have to go through the re-verification process again and make a new video, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In case there are changes to the OAuth consent screen after your app has been approved, then you will be required to re-verify your app again showing how you plan to use the Google user data you get from new scopes.